# Why I can sometimes use functions from nested modules without importing the whole path?

Tags: python, import, module, package, python-import

I was wondering what's the difference between these two cases? Is the inner structure of the modules somehow different?

So why this one works:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.random.RandomState
<class 'numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState'>
```

But this one doesn't work until I import the nested module also:

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> tkinter.ttk.Spinbox
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'ttk'
>>> import tkinter.ttk
>>> tkinter.ttk.Spinbox
<class 'tkinter.ttk.Spinbox'>
```

I think that this must be something to do with the `__init__.py` files in each module, but a concrete example of an implementation would be helpful.

Comment: It depends on how `__init__.py` is implemented for those packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of import behavior can be achieved by importing the deep class in the respective `__init__.py` files. Here's a quick demonstration of a project structure that works pretty much exactly like the real `numpy` and `tkinter` packages did:

```
.
├── main.py
├── numpy
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── random
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── mtrand.py
└── tkinter
    ├── __init__.py
    └── ttk.py
```

**`numpy/__init__.py`**:

```
from .random import RandomState
```

**`numpy/random/__init__.py`**:

```
from .mtrand import RandomState
```

**`numpy/random/mtrand.py`**:

```
class RandomState:
    pass
```

**`tkinter/__init__.py`**:

**`tkinter/ttk.py`**:

```
class Spinbox:
    pass
```

**`main.py`**:

```
import numpy
import tkinter

print(numpy.random.RandomState)

try:
    print(tkinter.ttk.Spinbox)
except AttributeError as e:
    print("Error:", e)
    import tkinter.ttk
    print(tkinter.ttk.Spinbox)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> <class 'numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState'>
> Error: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'ttk'
> <class 'tkinter.ttk.Spinbox'>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

By default, when you load a "package" (which is really just a directory with a __init__.py file, Python loads just the __init__.py file.

In that file, if you want, you can automatically load other things, such as modules (other .py files) and even other packages (dirs with __init__.py)

So the reason that those libraries differ is most likely due to a difference in how the __init__.py files are set up.

For instance, I've created a package with a single module. I have the module imported by the __init__.py file so that it loads automatically.

Comment: When someone designs a package with multiple modules and submodules, they can decide which, if any, of the modules and submodules get loaded automatically.